# Rendering asp.net tags stored in database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there any possible way to render text stored in the database as follows: <%: Html.ActionLink("exciting positions", "GetJobs", "Home")%> into a working link when displayed on mvc view page. I have researched for hours and still haven't found a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this You need to Render it 2 time First time Rendring to Get the text stored and second time to render the text You Got....Which is **NOT POSSIBLE** Because You can render only once

And Also this is Wrong way of Coding in ASP.NET